# Simple Markdown subset features in PHP

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I would like to allow only paragraphs and lists.

Actually i want to use the input to create a document in Open Document format. So I replace the tag `<p>` with the correct tag in ODF. But first, I'm trying to learn how to transform the markdown format into something I can use.

I could use the output of MarkdownPHP and replace tags in html to ODF tags, however i want to use only the paragraphs and lists. The Markdown generates much more than i need. If i miss any html tag the ODF document will break because it don't understand html tags.

I believe it is possible to use a simple RegExp. But I don't know how!

example:

```
My first line.

*    My first item.
*    My second item.

More text...
```

output:

```php
<p>My first line.</p>
<ul>
    <li>My first item.</li>
    <li>My second item.</li>
</ul>
<p>More text...</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`strip_tags()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all tags other than the ones you want. Their contents will remain, but the tags themselves will be removed.

Try this:

```
$output = strip_tags($output, "<p><ul><ol><li>");
```

From there, you can just use [`str_replace()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change the remaining tags into their ODF counterparts. (If the tag format isn't consistent coming out of your Markdown parser, then you can just use [`preg_replace()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to handle the differences depending on the specific output).

Comment: @Danilo You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark on this answer to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from **AgentConundrum**, i can solve the problem.
But I need run the parser 2 times because after the first time i will have blocks not wrapped.

```
$output = Markdown($output);
$output = strip_tags($output, '<p><ul><ol><li>');
$output = Markdown($output);
$output = strip_tags($output, '<p><ul><ol><li>');
```

Example:

```
This is an H1
=============

Paragraph here...

*    List item.
```

After this:

```
$output = Markdown($output);
$output = strip_tags($output, '<p><ul><ol><li>');
echo $output;
```

I will have this: (note the h1 title)

```
This is an H1

<p>Paragraph here...</p>

<ul>
    <li>List item.</li>
</ul>
```

So, i parse the output again:

```
<p>This is an H1</p>

<p>Paragraph here...</p>

<ul>
    <li>List item.</li>
</ul>
```